# Carousel Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, carousel

I am trying to change the background of each different carousel. How is that possible? Because I cant seem to do that.

```
<div id="carousel2">
    <el-carousel :interval="4000" type="card">
        <el-carousel-item v-for="item in 6" :key="item">
            <el-carousel-item style="background-color:green;" v-if="item === 1"></el-carousel-item>
            <h3>{{item}}</h3>
        </el-carousel-item>
    </el-carousel>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="carousel2">
  <el-carousel :interval="4000" type="card">
    // If background color
    <el-carousel-item v-for="item in twoItems" :key="item" :style="{ backgroundColor : item.bgColor }">
      <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
    </el-carousel-item>

    // If background image
    <el-carousel-item v-for="item in twoItems" :key="item" :style="{backgroundImage : `url(${ $item.bgImg })`}">
      <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
    </el-carousel-item>
  </el-carousel>
</div>
```

And your data in script:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        twoItems: [
          { title: 'Item One', bgColor: 'red', bgImg: 'lorem.jpg'  },
          { title: 'Item Two', bgColor: 'blue', bgImg: 'ipsum.jpg' },
        ],
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Would it be the same for background image ? { title: 'Item One', bgImage: url(' ') },  style="{ backgroundImage : item.bgImage }

Comment: Perfect. Thank You

Comment: {title:'Item One',bgImg:url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350")},                                            this is how I pass the url of the image, but it dosent seem to work

Comment: @JaslinKaur ping me let's figure out: skypeID: syed_haroon

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to set backgroundColor, then you can set in the style like

```
.el-carousel__item:nth-child(n) {
   background-color: green;
}
```

also you can finish it with `vue`:

```
<el-carousel-item :style="{ background: 'green' }" v-if="item === 1"></el-carousel-item>
     <h3>{{item}}</h3>
 </el-carousel-item>
```

Comment: If i should have 6 cards on the carousel, all of them would become the same color. How can I alter it so that each card is a different color? Thank You Tony

Comment: Pushing your color into an array, and then:
   :style="{ background: colorArray[item] }"